# Set cover facebook via PHP without notifications

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to set covers facebook via PHP SDK, when posting i set no_feed_story value 1. It' seems continue to notify users which are subscribed to the page

```
$args = array(
   'cover' => $coverid,
   'no_feed_story' => true,
   'access_token' => $access_token,
   'offset_y' => 90,
   'is_hidden' => true
    );

 try {
    $photo = $myfb->api($page_id, 'post', $args);

    } 

    catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception retournée: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue for almost 2 months!
This was not the case before, Facebook is not fixing it though.

I had opened a bug before, but they decided to close it yesterday since they believed not enough Users/developers had been impacted...

Please subscribe to the new bug here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/214524952029507 and complain!

Comment: I'm having same issue right now. + same code working for 2 other pages and there is no issue but the 3rd one working with problems.